# Groovy Source Code Question

Tags: groovy

Today i decided to see up Groovy source code and to built up my programming muscles in Groovy. I downloaded the Groovy Source code 1.8 from this [link](http://dist.groovy.codehaus.org/distributions/). But how do i proceed? In sense which folder first i have to see, so that i can understand better how groovy works(because there are many folders like benchmarks,bootstraps, src etc). May be this seems to be stupid question but i wanna to ask it.

Correct me if am worng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is inside `src/main`.
The unit tests all live inside `src/test`.

I found a good place to start looking was inside the huge class:

```
src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java
```

This is where a lot of the extra Groovy methods are defined, so you can pick your favourite function (such as `String.capitalize` for example) and find the definition of that method (around line `9561`, but that might be different in the version of the code you have downloaded)

You should then be able to (for example) change how something works, and check that the unit tests still function by calling

```
ant test
```

from the root folder, then you should see it build and test reports should be created and placed in the `target` folder

I tend to use a combination of `find` and `grep` to locate the area in the source that I am interested in, then slowly expand out from that class as I find other things that relate to it...

Hope this helps...it's a bit of a big question to try and cover

Comment: @ant [Ant is a build tool](http://ant.apache.org/).  Groovy also has a [Gradle build script](http://www.gradle.org/), but I always have more luck with `ant` for some reason...  This will change, as I know there are active steps towards just using the gradle build

Comment: @Ant's: Ant is a build tool, you of all people should know that :)

Comment: @don : i'm just a novice  have a great passion on Groovy, using it solve some puzzles on project Euler and having fun

Comment: @tim : thanks yates :) i guess you can put a book on Groovy :) and compete with Groovy In Action series :) you have a great knowledge in Groovy :) keep rocking :)

Comment: @Ant that was supposed to be a joke (based on your username)

Comment: "around line 9561": This DefaultGroovyMethods.java seems to be a huge class. When OOP was first popularized around 1990, writing a class with a few hundred methods was the primary signal that someone didn't really understand what OOP was all about.

Comment: @Vorg it doesn't seem to be, it is.  It contains all the decorations for the Java classes, so is not really an OOP issue.  I believe there is a movement underway to split it up into separate files per target class.

Comment: @Don : Oh sorry :D I took it in an another way ^_O